# How to check which background has a Textview?

Tags: android, textview

This may be kind of a stupid question. I have a large number of Textviews using 2 different background(Let's say, highlighted and not) and being accessed from different classes and updated very ofter, each class may highlight it or remove the highlight, and I would like to know
which textview is currently using the one or another background.

E.g

```
tetxviewN1.getBackground();
if (tetxviewN1.getBackground().equals(circle_black)){
my stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setTag()`  to store the state of textView if it's highlighted or not

```
textView.setTag("highlighted");
```

and to check it

```
String tag =(String)textView.getTag();
if (tag.equals("highlighted")){
 your stuff here
}
```